# Xbee 64-bit address in API mode

Tags: zigbee, xbee

I'm currently working on a project in which I use antennas such xbee XBee 2mW Wire Antenna - Series 2 (ZigBee Mesh).
how can I get my antenna64bit address so I can set it up using my software automatically? 
Can I send zigbee message to antenna so that it returns a message that contains it`s antenna address, then I decode the message and know the address of my antenna.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy way of doing this, you can send one message from the Router/End-Device to the Coordinator in your ZigBee network. You can use the special 16-bit Network Address 0x0000 to address the Coordinator.

This message should contain the 16-bit Network Address (or the 64-bit Address), so later the Coordinator can use this address in order to communicate back with this node. That is how you can do if you work with AT Mode. If you work with API Mode, the "Receive Packet" already contains the address of the sender, so you do not need to explicitely add it to your message.

Answer (score 0):

When you press one time the commission button: the module sends a node identification broadcast transmission.

Thus, I assume you are using the API mode, so from your Coordinator API (software side) you can send  a **Remote AT Command Request**, in *broadcast*, which set the **CB** (commission button) to **1**. This is the same of press the commission button virtually at one time. Here is the packet:

7E 00 10 **17** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FE 00 **43 42 01** 67

Then, when all your devices receive this packet, they should answer to the coordinator with a **Node Identification Indicator**, which contains their 16-bit and 64-bit address. This way, you can automatically set up your network on software.